# How to perform all other tasks once the asynchronous dispatch queue finishes execution

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, macos, asynchronous, deadlock

I have a PDFDocument where it has some actions on pages like delete,crop,rotate etc.

So when I click on the delete button and click on save(current thread : main thread)

```
-(void)save
{
    // -- process deleted pages first
            for( NSString* deletedPageId in self.deletedPageIdList )
            {
                [self.pdfCoordinator removePageWithId:deletedPageId];
            }
            // -- wait for all pages to delete before continuing
            [self.pdfCoordinator waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished];
            // few lines of code after this should run only when the above code finishes its execution
            // code to save the changes in the pdf to managedObject context

}
```

The code for removePageWithId:

```
- (void) removePageWithId:(NSString*)pageId
{
    NRMPDFOperation *op = [[NRMPDFOperation alloc] initWithNRMPDF:self
                                                           pageId:pageId
                                                         selector:@selector(removePageOpImpl:)
                                                             args:nil];
    [self addOperation:op];
    [op release];

}
```

above code creates an operation and adds it to the operation queue for each deletion of the page

code for removePageOpImpl:

```
- (NSError *)removePageOpImpl:(NRMPDFOperation *)op
{
    NSError* error = [self loadDocument];
    if( !error )
    {
        NSUInteger index = [self pageIndexForId:[op pageId]];
        if( index < [self pageCount] )
        {
                    [[self pdfDocument] removePageAtIndex:index];
                    [[self mutablePageIdList] removeObjectAtIndex:index];
                    [self updatePageLabelsFromIndex:index];
                    [self updateChangeCount:NSChangeDone];
                    self.contentsChanged = YES;
        }
        else
        {
            // TODO: error
        }
    }
    return error;
}
```

In the removePageOpImpl: method the line of code 
[[self pdfDocument] removePageAtIndex:index]; internally executing some tasks on main thread(but we are making the main thread to wait until this operation finishes).which causes the deadlock.

I tried to execute the code inside removePageOpImpl: in an asynchronous dispatch queue to avoid the deadlock.below is the code for that

```
- (NSError *)removePageOpImpl:(NRMPDFOperation *)op
{
    NSError* error = [self loadDocument];
    if( !error )
    {
        NSUInteger index = [self pageIndexForId:[op pageId]];
        if( index < [self pageCount] )
        {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [[self pdfDocument] removePageAtIndex:index];
                    [[self mutablePageIdList] removeObjectAtIndex:index];
                    [self updatePageLabelsFromIndex:index];
                    [self updateChangeCount:NSChangeDone];
                    self.contentsChanged = YES;
                    });
        }
        else
        {
            // TODO: error
        }
    }
    return error;
}
```

Now I am out from the deadlock. But another issue is by putting the above code into asynchronous block the code which should run after this tasks is executing before this, because of that my app is not behaving as expected.

Code inside waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished method

```
- (void) addOperation:(NRMPDFOperation*)operation
{
    [_operationSet addObject:operation];
    [[self operationQueue] addOperation:operation];
}


- (void) waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished
{
    [[self operationQueue] waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished];
}



 - (NSOperationQueue *)operationQueue
{
    if( !_operationQueue )
    {
        NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
        [queue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1];
        _operationQueue = queue;
    }
    return _operationQueue;
}
```

This is how the original Save method looks like :

```
- (void)saveDocumentWithDelegate:(id)delegate didSaveSelector:(SEL)didSaveSelector contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
{
    // TODO: don't just ignore saveOperation

    __block BOOL success = YES;
    __block NSError *error = nil;

    /* write back field changes */  
    if ([item hasChangesInEditFieldsetFor:@"values"] )
    {
        //Some code
    }


    if( self.isPDFEdited )
    {

        // -- process deleted pages first
            for( NSString* deletedPageId in self.deletedPageIdList )
            {
                [self.itemPDFCoordinator removePageWithId:deletedPageId];
            }
            // -- wait for all pages to delete before continuing
            [self.itemPDFCoordinator waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished];


            // -- replace the search text any pages we deleted
            if( [self.deletedPageIdList count] )
            {
                [self.item setValue:[self.editPDF string] forKeyPath:@"dict.values._searchText"];
            }

        NSMutableDictionary* originalRotations = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:
                                                  [self.itemPDFCoordinator pageCount]];
        for( NSString* pageId in self.itemPDFCoordinator.pageIdList )
        {
            NSInteger rotation = [[self.itemPDFCoordinator pageForId:pageId] rotation];
            [originalRotations setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:rotation] forKey:pageId];
        }

        // -- now process actions on remaining pages (crop, rotate, and convert to b&w)
        BOOL didCropAnyPages = NO;
        NSMutableArray* convertToBwJobs = [NSMutableArray array];
        for( NSString* pageId in [self.pageActionDict allKeys] )
        {
            NSArray* actions = [self.pageActionDict objectForKey:pageId];
            for( NSDictionary* action in actions )
            {
                NSNumber* rotationNumber = [action objectForKey:@"rotation"];
                NSValue* cropRectVal = [action objectForKey:@"cropRect"];
                NSNumber* convertToBlackAndWhite = [action objectForKey:@"convertToBlackAndWhite"];

                if( rotationNumber )
                {
                    [self.itemPDFCoordinator rotateByDegrees:[rotationNumber integerValue]
                                               forPageWithID:pageId];
                }
                else if( cropRectVal )
                {
                    [self.itemPDFCoordinator setNormalizedBounds:[cropRectVal rectValue]
                                                          forBox:kPDFDisplayBoxCropBox
                                                   forPageWithID:pageId];
                    // -- set a flag so we know to recrop the entire document
                    didCropAnyPages = YES;
                }
                else if( [convertToBlackAndWhite boolValue] )
                {
                    NSUInteger pageIndex = [self.itemPDFCoordinator pageIndexForId:pageId];
                    NRMJob* job = [NRMAppJobFactory convertToBlackAndWhiteJobForItem:self.item
                                                                           pageIndex:pageIndex];
                    [convertToBwJobs addObject:job];
                }
            }
        }

        // -- reapply crop box to any cropped pages
        if( didCropAnyPages )
        {
            [self.itemPDFCoordinator applyCropBoxToAllPages];
        }

        [self.itemPDFCoordinator waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished];

        for( NRMJob* job in convertToBwJobs )
        {
            if( ![[self.masterDocument docjob] addJob:job forItem:self.item error:&error] )
                [NSApp presentError:error];
            else
                [job waitUntilDone];
        }

        // -- make sure document attributes are updated
        NSDictionary *docDict = [self.itemPDFCoordinator documentAttributes];
        NSDictionary *newDict = [(NRMItem *)item updateDocumentAttributes:docDict];
        if (![newDict isEqualToDictionary:docDict])
            [self.itemPDFCoordinator setDocumentAttributes:newDict];

        [self.itemPDFCoordinator waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished];

        // -- check if we need to reprocess any pages
        for( NSString* pageId in self.itemPDFCoordinator.pageIdList )
        {
            NSInteger oldRotation = [[originalRotations objectForKey:pageId] integerValue];
            NSInteger newRotation = [[self.itemPDFCoordinator pageForId:pageId] rotation];
            if( oldRotation != newRotation )
            {
                // -- if it's an image page and we already have OCR data for it, we should reanalyze
                NSUInteger pageIndex = [self.itemPDFCoordinator pageIndexForId:pageId];
                BOOL isPageImage = [self.itemPDFCoordinator isImagePageAtIndex:pageIndex DPI:NULL];
                if( isPageImage && [item OCRDataForPageIndex:pageIndex] )
                {
                    NRMJob* job = [NRMAppJobFactory reprocessPageJobForItem:self.item 
                                                                  pageIndex:pageIndex];
                    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                             selector:@selector(reanalyzeJobFinished:)
                                                                 name:kNRMJobFinishedNotification
                                                               object:job];
                    success = [[self.masterDocument docjob] addJob:job forItem:self.item error:&error];
                    if( !success )
                    {
                        if( error )
                            [self presentError:error];
                    }
                        //goto bail;
                }
            }
        }

        //Force Save of PDF to Disk
        [self.itemPDFCoordinator setManagedObjectContext:[item managedObjectContext]];
        [self.itemPDFCoordinator saveChanges];
}

    if( success )
    {
        [self updateChangeCount:NSChangeCleared];
        if( self.isPDFEdited )
        {
            // !CLEARSPLIT! please do not remove this comment
            [self.item setValue:nil forKeyPath:@"dict.values._splitId"];

            if( ![self loadPDFForItem:item error:&error] )
                goto bail;
        }
    }

bail:
    if( error )
        [self presentError:error];

    if( delegate )
    {
        /* signature: 
         - (void)document:(NSDocument *)document didSave:(BOOL)didSaveSuccessfully  contextInfo:(void  *)contextInfo;
         */
        objc_msgSend( delegate, didSaveSelector, self, (error ? NO : YES), contextInfo );
    }
}
```

can anyone suggest me how can I get out of this issue.

Comment: @Jody Hagins : Here is the new question

Comment: You can run synchronously on the main queue.  Can be safe as long as THIS code isn't executing on the main queue.  I find your asynchronous transfer of the index, which is itself dependent upon the value of the document, which is being modified elsewhere, very suspicious - worst case can cause a crash, less worse case may occasionally delete the wrong page (depending upon what else is going in in your program.  If you do this, you should take immense care with other threads reading and writing your pdsDocument and pageIdList.

Comment: When I run this code in synchronous main queue the app getting freezed. where it generate semaphore_wait_trap

Comment: without knowing what else it going on in your app, it's not possible to debug it.

Comment: @AlexBrown: Please see my previous post. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33253779/pdfdocument-removepageatindex-is-not-working-when-updated-to-mac-os-x-10-11

Comment: The problem is that you are waiting in the main for something that itself is waiting for something to run on the main thread, which is giving your deadlock.  Post the code for `waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished`.

Comment: @jody Hagins : Updated the post with the code waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished

Answer (score 0):

Rather than calling `waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished` (which blocks a thread), I'd suggest specifying an additional completion operation, which you can make dependent upon the other operations finishing:

```
-(void)save {
    NSOperation *completionOperation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
        // whatever you want to do when it's done
    }];

    for (NSString* deletedPageId in self.deletedPageIdList) {
        NSOperation *operation = [self.pdfCoordinator removePageWithId:deletedPageId];
        [completionOperation addDependency:operation];
    }

    // add this completionOperation to a queue, but it won't actually start until the other operations finish

    [queue addOperation:completionOperation];
}
```

Clearly this assumes that you change `removePageWithId` to return the operation it added to the queue:

```
- (NSOperation *)removePageWithId:(NSString*)pageId {
    NRMPDFOperation *operation = [[NRMPDFOperation alloc] initWithNRMPDF:self
                                                                  pageId:pageId
                                                                selector:@selector(removePageOpImpl:)
                                                                    args:nil];
    [self addOperation:operation];
    [operation release];
    return operation;
}
```

This way, you're not blocking any thread waiting for the operations to finish, but simply specify what to do when they do finish.

Comment: Intresting, Let me try with this approach.

Comment: No this is not working in my case. still the app is hanging ;(

Comment: This is the standard `NSOperation` approach, as one should generally never call `waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished`. So you've completely commented out that method and you're not calling it anywhere else in your code, are you? Assuming you've done that, you need to just identify where the code is blocking. I'm not sure we have enough to diagnose where that's going wrong.

Comment: Let me post the save function how it exactly looks like

Comment: I posted the original save method please check it and suggest where I am doing wrong.

Comment: There are a ton of these `wait...` functions in there and if any of the operations for which they they are waiting employ the main thread, you'll deadlock. I'd personally get refactor out all of all of those `wait...` calls, but I can see that's not entirely trivial in this case. Alternatively, narrow down where exactly you're dead locking and start with that one and go from there.